# Tensorboard only shows one image

Tags: python, tensorboard

I am running tensorflow for object detection.

However, the tensorboard only show the result of one image.

I tried to follow the suggestion of changing `optional uint32 num_visualizations = 10 [default=10];` in the file `eval.proto`.

However, only one image appeared again.

How to solve the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is some discussion happening here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636600/tensorflow-1-9-object-detection-model-main-py-only-evaluates-one-image/52068798#52068798

Comment: Thank you, Aplln.